# Words for encourage, hearten, embolden

Tags: выбор-слова, значения, словоупотребление

Let's say your friend got a new job, but the first week was awful. What would the right word for *encouraging* your friend to not quit the job immediately, but to go on.

Some possibilities seem to be

- воодушевлять
- вдохновлять
- ободрять
- подбодрять
- поощрять
- ... давать смелость, вселять мужество, придавать бодрости, внушать бодрость

But I cannot figure out which of these are really commonly used, e. g. I was told *поощрять* you'd say to a child only. I also think that *развеселить* is inept, as it's more like *amuse* with the aim of changing ones (superficial) mood.

So what is the word to choose and how can those given words be used?

Comment: **Приободрить** would be one more appropriate word that has not been mentioned so far

Comment: Perhaps there is an ambiguity in the question. Whether you like to describe the process of encouraging (*я пробую вдохновить его*) or word to the friend (*cheer up!*)?

Comment: @putnik It's about the first one, I think. It just shouldn't be a formal term/phrase which would sound strange when used in speech.

Comment: @embert My choice is *поддержать/подбодрять*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case we would use **ободрять-ободрить** or **подбодрять-подбодрить**. Вселять-вселить мужество, придавать-придать бодрости and внушать-внушить бодрость are all synonyms of **ободрять**, but are not commonly used, I would say they are quite bookish.

I have never heard of the expression **давать смелость**.

We use the verb **ободрять-ободрить** when we want to encourage a person because he (she) is in a bad mood or something bad happened. **Подбодрять-подбодрить** means "encourage a little bit".

- Я ободрил друга, сказав ему, что это временные трудности.

  Она приободрила сына и сказала: "Ничего, в следующем году экзамены
  сдашь, не беда!".

**Поощрять-поощрить** is used when we give smth to a person (not only a child) if he (she) did something which was good (correct). It can be translated into English as "reward" or "praise"

- Режиссёр поощрял оригинальные идеи артистов.

**Воодушевлять-воодушевить** means "to inspire smb to do smth", "fill with enthusiasm", "inspirit". It is used with the preposition **на** and the Accusative case.

- Рассказ воодушевил художника на создание полотна.

**Вдохновлять-вдохновить** means "to inspire smb to do smth". It is a synonym of **воодушевлять-воодушевить**, but is normally used with artistic or scientific work.

- Паук-акробат вдохновил учёных на создание робота.

Comment: поощрять и материально поощрять это не одно и тоже )

Answer (score 2):

In the described situation I can think of one commonly used word: **поддержать**

All other listed words are more formal *in this case* (maybe, except **подбодрять**).

Please note you hardly can say "**я поддерживаю тебя**" when you are speaking to the friend with tricky job  but absolutely can "**я поддержал его**" when you're relating the story to someone else.

Comment: So *я хотел подбодрить тебя не вешать голову.* or *Я подбодрил его укрепляющими словами* is possible? Or you'd hardly hear somebody say so? Any common non-formal words which one can use?

Comment: Something like "я хотел подбодрить тебя чтобы ты не вешал нос/не опускал руки" (I'm not sure that "вешать голову" is widely used in phrases like this) would be totally fine, second one is almost OK, except that we don't say "укрепляющие слова", you can say something like "приободряющие слова", but "подбодрил приободряющими словами" sounds tautologically.

Comment: @embert I'd say *я хотел поддержать/подбодрить тебя* if I spoke to a friend, but please note you're using Past Tense here. Sure thing you can say *я поддерживаю тебя* but in sense *I agree with your decision* not in sense of encourage. Another example is *я подбадриваю тебя, чтоб  у тебя все получилось* but we rather have Present Perfect here :) and this sentence does not contain any encourage itself, just description/explanation. 
Non-formal may be *Я с ним поговорил, и его пропёрло* if you want to make an accent on the success of the action.

Comment: @embert Also you can *зажечь идеей/желанием (преодолеть)*